# Entity Framework Code First Database not Created After Project ported to VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC5 VS2012 project that I ported to VS2013. The project uses entity framework code first to create the required databases. It worked fine on my machine after I ported it. The database is still in (localdb)\v11.0.

The problem I'm having is that if I try to run the project locally on a NEW machine (fresh windows/VS installation), the first time it runs it tries to create the database in (localdb)\v11.0 rather than (localdb)\ProjectsV12. As far as I can tell, the new machine does not have a (localdb)\v11.0. Running the project fails at the first time it tries to access the database with a SqlException for the expected database not being found. I added this line to my DbContext class so I'm pretty sure that the DbContext wants to create the db in (localdb)\v11.0.

```
Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

The connection string reported by this debug line is:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachedDbFilenname=|DataDirectory|MyDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

(this was suggested at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx).

I confirmed that the expected database is not in (localdb)\ProjectsV12.

I tried updating the Web.Config file default connection to be:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

... but the app still wants to create the db in (localDB)\v11.0.

I am using VS 2013 Web Express on the new machine (where it doesn't work) and VS 2013 Ultimate on the old machine (where it does work).

How can I get the project to create the db in the local database that is there rather than in v11.0? Or is there another approach I should take here?

**Update1:** 
I created a new MVC application and it seems the default localdb is (localdb)\mssqllocaldb. I tried setting the connection string in my project to mssqllocaldb, but still hit the same problem. So, I tried creating another new MVC applicaiton in Visual Studio 2013 with the intention of "transplanting" my site into it. I took all the models, controllers, views, controller factory from my project (the one that won't create the database) and copied it to the new app.  After a lot of readding references and nuget packages and making some minor tweaks to web.config, the project works as expected and creates a database in the mssqllocaldb. So there must be some configuration in my original project that's not allowing it to create a database. I still need to get the original project working -- any suggestions of how I can figure out what causes the difference?

**Update2:**

I don't understand how, but this problem has something to do with code first migrations.  I have a file called Configuration.cs in the Migrations folder of my project. When I delete the contents of the file, the database is created as expected. The contents of the Migrations folder are:

```
   namespace MvcApp.Migrations
    {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MvcApp.Models.DbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MvcApp.Models.DbContext context)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Deleting the entire contents of that file makes database creation work as expected.  Keep in mind:

- The project still works with the configuration on my original PC. It only had problems on the new PC, where the database needed to be provisioned.
- Removing parts of the Configuration class (e.g., just the Seed method) doesn't work, I need to remove the whole class.

**Update3:**
If I set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true in the configuration.cs file, it still fails. However, if I set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true AND I delete the one checked in migration file I have (201412312047199_AddSpreadsheetIdColumn.cs), then it works as expected.  Is EF Migrations having trouble creating the database when it thinks it also needs to add columns to a table?

Does anyone have any insight into what's going on here? Will be I causing problems down the road or problems for the live site if I just remove the contents of Configuration.cs?

Thanks!